# Convolution Neural Network and multiple class classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a CNN model that classifies time series data into three classes: A,B,C. Class C is the hardest one to detect because it is somehow close to A and B, but A and B are different. 
 I have a balanced dataset of around 60,000 samples. The model performs well for classifying A and B with F1 score of 75%,80% for each class, but not good with the third class C which gives F1 score of 55%.

If I want to enhance the results of C, is it a good idea to add more train samples for C more than the other two classes (A and B), instead of the balanced dataset? How can I make the model give more importance to C without over fitting to C?

Answer (score 1):

Over-fitting the network will not improve classification of test data. The safer route is to improve the representation of each class.

Imbalanced classes will bias the network toward the majority class. You can try [sub-sampling](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-train-convolutional-neural-networks-on-highly-unbalanced-datasets) the data to offset the imbalance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question so I guess I'll give a general answer: Your options are to either try to find better features to use in your classification, or to over-fit for C. Whether or not it's a "good" idea depends on what you're using it for and what you consider to be an acceptable probability of error.

In any classification exercise, whether its CNN or some other method, there will always be trade-offs, especially if two or more of the data sets have any degree of overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering does it always cause over-fitting if I used unbalanced dataset? lets say I used 40% as C : 30% as B: 30% as A

Comment: @ryh12 Technically speaking, no, this will not necessarily result in overfitting. But it may result in an unintended bias in your model as stu mentions below. The obvious question to ask is how accurate is your training data? You may want to consider pruning your training set instead.